# Use npm library for django on runserver environment

Tags: python, node.js, django

I made static folder in my root project.

in `settins.py`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Install `npm` library under `static` directory.

```
myproject/static$ npm -i js-cookie
```

then There comes the files like this

```
myproject/static/node_modules/js.cookie/dist/js.cookie.min.js
```

then run server

```
myproject$ python manage.py runserver
```

then use in template.html

However this shows the error

```
GET http://localhost:8000/static/node_modules/js.cookie/dist/js.cookie.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I have two quesitons.

1. Is it good practice to use npm library under django project??
2. Maybe `runserver` doesn't use `mypoject/static`?